# What is the difference between GDAL geometry Within() vs Contains() functions?

Tags: gdal

What is the differences in following functions available in org.gdal.ogr.Geometry.

```
Within() vs Contains()

Crosses() vs Intersect()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `within` and `contains` functions are reciprocal functions. *a* `contains` *b*, if and only if, *b* is `within` *a*. The C++ [source code](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/blob/master/src/geom/Geometry.cpp#L385), says the same:

```
bool
Geometry::within(const Geometry* g) const
{
    return g->contains(this);
}
```

The crosses() and intersects() function have different implementation.

According to this [documentation page](http://geos.refractions.net/ro/doxygen_docs/html/classgeos_1_1geom_1_1Geometry.html#a26), intersects return true if disjoint returns false, and the disjoint predicate means that the two geometries have no point in common. We can conclude that intersects means that the two geometries have at least one point in common.

In the other hand, the crosses predicate means that the geometries have some but not all interior points in common. Which is more restrictive than the intersects predicate.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks a lot @Ortomala

Answer (score 1):

[Ortomala Lokni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1807667/ortomala-lokni) is correct about `crosses` and `intersects`, Here is a visual explanation of how within and contains work.

Say that you have two geometries: The point `A` and the polygon `B` like shown on the image
[image: Polygon]

Then A is **within** B, while B **contains** A.

The inverse is **not true**. A does not contains B and B is not within A.

the following two statements are true:

`A.within(B) -> B.contains(A)`

`A.contains(B) -> B.within(A)`

Comment: Thank you, I've modified my answer.